# How to Vertically Center a div in a @page and print (DomPDF & Laravel)

Tags: html, css, laravel, dompdf

Good day! I'm currently working with the DomPDF Library of Laravel 8 to generate a Printable PDF from using native CSS (as Bootstrap and other imports don't work well with this library).

I find it hard formatting certain divisions to fit the dead center of a page. I can't find any resources on centering things vertically in printable formats such as in DomPDF.

Margin only handles the left and right sides, while the top and bottom ones don't have any effect.

My CSS Sample

```
@page
{
    margin-right: 1.5cm;
    margin-left: 1.5cm;
    size:8.5in 11in;
}

.page
{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
}

.page-break
{
    page-break-after: always;
}

.intro-title-block
{
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

DomPDF Sample Snippet
[image: DomPDF sample snip]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: table` and `display: table-cell`

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <!-- Your content here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox is not supported by DomPDF, I solved it using this code:

```
.page{
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can style the page with the flex display.

```
.page{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
```

Comment: DomPDF does not support flexbox